# Simple mixxing warter in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have flask and beaker, but water and particle is difference game object, so what I want is when flask pour water into beaker, it will change weight. What should I do?

I try to use beaker script to make it have weight, and when I place it at plate, it doesn't show my weight.

```
public class Beaker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text ro1;
    public Image img;
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Beaker")
        {
            ro1.text = "100g";
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]